# Declare var in Scala not as either null or None

Tags: scala

So I have a Trait, where I need to have concrete member variables. Those variables are assigned values through an init method though. So, when I declare them, I have to assign them null. Another option is to use None, but then I have to declare them as Option[T], which I don't want either.

So, my question is, can I declare a yet unassigned var in Scala as neither null or None?

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using `abstract class` instead of `trait`?

Comment: Why not have the init method instantiate the trait containing only immutable values instead? I see you have a C background, but for Scala this kind of coding style is highly discouraged.

Comment: @MarkusAppel Can you maybe give an example.

Comment: @MetallicPriest Something like [this](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/nU3F5hv/1).

Comment: But you are not using a Trait, which I need to.

Answer (score 4):

My first attempt would be to use `abstract class`:

```
abstract class Test(arg1: Int, arg2: String) {

   val calculatedInConstructor1 = ??? // use args here
   val calculatedInConstructor2 = ??? // use args here
}

new Test(1, "test") {}
```

if that was not possible for some reason, then still i could be achieved using something like:

```
trait Test {

  // have to be provided in implementation
  protected val arg1: Int
  protected val arg2: String

  // lazy will defer initialization so you can provide
  // arg1 and arg2 in class extending Test
  lazy val calculatedOnFirstUse1 = ??? // use args here
  lazy val calculatedOnFirstUse2 = ??? // use args here
}

new Test {
  val arg1 = 1
  val arg2 = "test"
}
```

No reason for using `var`s, `null`s etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can define them as methods instead:

```
 trait Test {

  def arg1: Int
  def arg2: String

}

val x=new Test {
  def arg1=1
  def arg2 = "test"
}
```

you can also override as val

```
val y=new Test {
  val arg1=2
  val arg2="test2"
}

val z= new Test{
  val arg1=3 // won't compile
}
x.arg1
x.arg2
y.arg1
y.arg2
```

Comment: I need to use them in an extended Class.